# Hosting mongodb using the dropbox

Tags: mongodb, ampps

My goal is to have ampps on two computer and have all files stay in sync via Dropbox.  Not sure how this is done correctly.  I understand adding Ammps folder to Dropbox but not sure what you mean by creating symlink.

Also is any other step I should be aware of when attempting.  I have installed Ammpps.  Thanks for the help. I am creating a Grails project and I am using a MongoDB database.

Comment: symlink is a symbolic link.  Some info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/)

Comment: You could also directly sync your two machines without a server in between. E.g. [BitTorrentSync](http://www.getsync.com/) or [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/)

Comment: You definitely don't want to have your MongoDB `dbpath` in a Dropbox folder; this would be an easy way to accidentally corrupt your database by having conflicting updates from multiple computers. See: [Syncing a mongodb database over dropbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607146/syncing-a-mongodb-database-over-dropbox). You could share your Grails application folder by creating this under your Dropbox path, but a more typical way to synchronize code would be using a version control system like `git`.